# How to fix "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker/8a06898d8e300771d98f9877d1aa61003fb456d57d98a3706c99/cpuacct.usage"

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am trying to build elasticsearch multi-node containers using docker. It's not communicating both nodes, we are using ES OSS version (elasticsearch-oss-7.9.3-no-jdk-linux-x86_64.tar.gz) for multi-node instances. The following docker-compose.yml file executing properly, but it's not listing the nodes, always showing a single node (refer the attached image here) and also getting the following exception message while accessing node endpoint..

Docker-compose.yml,

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  es01:
    image: es-oss:latest
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - jvm_args_memory=512m
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - es_network_host=es01
      - es.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - log_level_root=debug
      - log_level_sample=debug
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - /home/centos/dev/dockerdata/es01:/var/lib/esdata
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

  es02:
    image: es-oss:latest
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - jvm_args_memory=512m
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - es_network_host=es02
      - es.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - log_level_root=debug
      - log_level_sample=debug
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - /home/centos/dev/dockerdata/es02:/var/lib/esdata
```

**Error logs:**

```
[![java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker/7a11d2fe8a5fbbda8bbc41fd9b2a185875a1e78dd9b3dc5ea62b922be9d35999/cpuacct.usage
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92) ~\[?:?\]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106) ~\[?:?\]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~\[?:?\]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219) ~\[?:?\]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:375) ~\[?:?\]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:426) ~\[?:?\]
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420) ~\[?:?\]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160) ~\[?:?\]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2916) ~\[?:?\]
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3396) ~\[?:?\]
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3436) ~\[?:?\]
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.readSingleLine(OsProbe.java:235) ~\[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.readSysFsCgroupCpuAcctCpuAcctUsage(OsProbe.java:324) ~\[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.getCgroupCpuAcctUsageNanos(OsProbe.java:311) ~\[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.getCgroup(OsProbe.java:533) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsProbe.osStats(OsProbe.java:659) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.OsService.<init>(OsService.java:50) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.MonitorService.<init>(MonitorService.java:46) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:409) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) \[elasticsearch-cli-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.Elasticsearch. cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) \[elasticsearch-cli-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) \[elasticsearch-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3\]][1]][1]
```

[image: Listing single node]

Any inputs here are really appreciated.